# C / C++ Putting a string into a two dimensional array?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string, stdin

Hey very new to c/c++ and was hoping I could get pushed in the right direction on fixing my errors.

I am creating a program that opens a file and reads the text in the file and puts it into a string. From there I create a two dimensional array that finds the size of it by getting the square root of the smallest perfect square that the string can fit into.Now we get to where I am having trouble, from this step I am trying to put the string into the array row by column using the following code.

```
          char newarray[b][b]; //b being the square root of the closest perfect square.
   57
   58     //put string into arrray;
   59     for(int row=0; row < b; row++)
   60     {
   61         for(int column=0;column < b; column++)
   62         {
   63             newarray[row][column] = newstring[row];
   64         }
   65     }
```

But when I print this array it comes out where each individual letter of the text fills up each element in that row.

i.e.

```
 string s= "supercalifragilistic";
 char[5][5];

 // I want it to come out like this
 0 1 2 3 4 5
 1 s u p e r
 2 c a l i f
 3 f r a g i
 4 l i s t i
 5 c

 //but it comes out like this
 0 1 2 3 4 5
 1 s s s s s
 2 u u u u u
 3 p p p p p
 4 e e e e e
 5 r r r r r
```

Comment: newarray[row][column] = newstring[row + b*column];

Comment: so C **xor** C++? You can't program in two languages at the same time. The solution depends a lot on which language you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a different index for the source string.

```
char newarray[b][b]; //b being the square root of the closest perfect square.

//put string into arrray;
int i=0;
for(int row=0; row < b; row++)
{
  for(int column=0;column < b; column++, i++)
  {
    newarray[row][column] = newstring[i];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You only have to declare an integer variable to specify in which character of your String you are at this exactly moment, and increment it after each assignment.

```
char newarray[b][b]; //b being the square root of the closest perfect square.
int counter = 0;

for(int row = 0; row < b; row++){
  for(int column=0;column < b; column++){
    newarray[row][column] = newstring[counter];
    counter++;
  }     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a different index for traversing the string.

In the current code, make the modification:

```
 int k=0;
 for(int row=0; row < b; row++)
    {
        for(int column=0;column < b; column++)
        {
            newarray[row][column] = newstring[k++];
        }
    }
```

This is because: in previous code, this is how `newarray` was filled:

```
 Say, b = 2

 newarray[0][0] = newstring[0];
 newarray[0][1] = newstring[0];
 newarray[0][2] = newstring[0];
 newarray[1][0] = newstring[1];
 newarray[0][1] = newstring[1];
```

and so on.

However, you wanted something like:

```
 newarray[0][0] = newstring[0];
 newarray[0][1] = newstring[1];
 newarray[0][2] = newstring[2];
 newarray[1][0] = newstring[3];
 newarray[0][1] = newstring[4];
```

and so on.
One way is to use a variable, say `k` to vary from `0` to `string length` for the `newstring`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not contain sufficient information, but if I understood your problem correctly, inside the inner `for` loop, you're not incrementing the *index* for `newstring`.

You need to change

```
newarray[row][column] = newstring[row];
```

to

```
newarray[row][column] = newstring[(row * b) +column];
```

Comment: Do you mean [row*b+column] ?